# Adding User class object to GenericList<T> class giving error in Java (ClassCastException)

Tags: java, classcastexception

I am learning Java currently and I cannot seem to figure out why there is ClassCastException. I looked through many examples here but still cannot seem to wrap my head around the problem at hand. Here's my code:

**GenericList.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GenericList<T extends User> {
    private T[] items = (T[]) new Object[10]; // error here on debugging
    private int count;

    public void add(T item) {
        items[count++] = item;
    }

    public T get(int index) {
        return items[index];
    }

    public String getCompleteUserList() {
        return Arrays.deepToString(items);
    }
}
```

**User.java**

```
public class User implements Comparable<User> {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    private GenericList<User> userList = new GenericList<>(); // error here on debugging
    
    public User(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;        
        userList.add(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(User otherUser) {
        return this.age - otherUser.age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name = " + this.name + "; Age = " + this.age;
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var user1 = new User("User 1", 25); // error on this line during debugging
        var user2 = new User("User 2", 24);
    }
}
```

I tried debugging the code and the lines in question are indicated in the code above. I am not getting why it is throwing the error though? What am I missing?

The idea is to store the newly created user object in the Generic User list items array and then later print the complete list of users using **getCompleteUserList** method.

I have spent more than 2 hours on this to no avail. I am sure it is the most basic and stupid thing I am missing somewhere, but don't know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object[]` cannot be cast to `T[]` since `T` is [erased](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) to `User` due to the `T extends User` bound. Store an `Object[]` then cast individual items to `T` when needed:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GenericList<T extends User> {
    // this is Object[] now
    private Object[] items = new Object[10];
    private int count;

    public void add(T item) {
        items[count++] = item;
    }

    public T get(int index) {
        // need a cast to T here
        return (T) items[index];
    }

    public String getCompleteUserList() {
        return Arrays.deepToString(items);
    }
}
```

Comment: Object can normally be cast to T, as long as T gets erased to Object. It doesn't here only because T was written up as being bounded by User, thus, it erases to that.

Comment: This is the correct solution, but the incorrect explanation. @A G's answer has the correct explanation.

Comment: Wouldn't the get method now result in a class cast when the items array containing Objects is cast to T(which extends User?)

Comment: @AG Yes, it would, but the cast won't error due to all the items in the array being of type T.

Comment: Thanks. So basically, the whole issue if I understood correctly was related to T becoming User object because I extended T with User. 

This makes it impossible to type cast Object (Parent) to User[] (Child). Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

The Class cast exception here is because you have Generic list templatized with an Object that "extends" User... and in the first like you try to assign Object who is not a sub-class of User to it.

Should be

```
private T[] items = (T[]) new User[10];
```

Comment: This is the correct explanation, but the incorrect solution. The other answer (by @Aplet123) is the correct solution (We can get into why, but perhaps it is enough to state that java's own ArrayList works like @Aplet123's answer).